# Is there a deterministic way to find such a matrix $X=AS$ basic linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrices $X \in \mathbb R^{512 \times 768}$, $A\in \mathbb R^{512 \times 50}$.

I'm looking for a matrix $S\in \mathbb R^{50 \times 768}$ such that $X=AS$.

Is there an algorithm that does this? is there a deterministic way to solve this problem?

Comment: If it has a solution, you can compute it with a LU decomposition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Comment: Hint: Each column of S is a solution of a linear system.

Comment: I tried using Moore-Penrose left psuedoinverse (of A), and indeed I get a matrix $S$ that is $50 \times 768$, but I don't get $X=AS$...

Comment: Then, it has no solution

Comment: If $X$ is "random", then $X$ has likely rank $512$. However $AS$ has rank $50$ at most. So the system has likely no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ full-rank matrix with $m>n$, then $A$ has a left inverse
$$
A_{\mathrm{left}}^{-1}=(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top
$$
that satisfies $A_{\mathrm{left}}^{-1}A=I_n$. Full-rank means that $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)=\min\{m,n\}$.

Thus, if a solution exists, then in your case we have
$$
S=A_{\mathrm{left}}^{-1}X=(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top X
$$
provided that $A$ is full rank. Consequently this can be used to prove whether or not a solution exists.

Comment: That is only true, if the system has a solution. As @OriaGruber's comment indicates, the system has no solution.

Comment: As said in the comments, I tried the left inverse, but I don't get that $A^{-1}_{left}A=I$. I guess my matrix isn't full rank.

Comment: @OriaGruber What is the rank of your matrix? Without more information it will be hard to give an answer.

Comment: $A$ is rank $50$

Comment: @OriaGruber That's full-rank...

Comment: I know, that's why its strange. Obviously I'm doing all of these calculations in a computer and not by hand, I defined $B$ to be the psuedo inverse of $A$, and defined $S$ to be $BX$, and when I checked what is $X-AS$ i didnt get anything close to the zero matrix.

Comment: The pseudo inverse is not an *inverse* for rectangular matrices. $A^+ b$ solve $\min_{x} \| Ax - b \|$ such that $x$ has minimal norm. If $b$ isn't in the range of $A$, then $AA^+b \ne b$.

Comment: As such I don't expect it to be exactly $X=AS$, but any approximation will do. I'm not getting a good approximation at all. Indeed, $BA$ is very very close to the identity matrix, but when I define $S=BX$ and then check what is $X-AS$, I don't get anythin close to zero matrix. All of the matrices here have "ugly" entries. random numbers, decimals.

Comment: btw. computing the pseudo inverse is more expansive than a LU decomposition...

Comment: @user251257 But $A$ is *injective* so any solution has to be of the form given in my answer. This method can thus be used to prove that the system has no solutions.

Comment: Yes... It also gives the minimizer of $\min_S \| AS - X \|_{F}$. Just, don't claim $AA^{-1}_{\mathrm{left}} X = X$.

Comment: @OriaGruber There's no reason to expect that $X-BAX$ "looks small". Heuristically, if some of the columns of $X$ are "far away" from the image of $A$, then one would actually expect $X-BAX$ to be "large".

Comment: @OriaGruber $BA$ is only the identity on the range of $A$, nothing more, nothing less. And $BX$ is the minimizer of $\min_S\| X-AS \|_F$. So you can't do better.

Comment: I can't do better? Even though $A$ is full rank? Maybe I can't do better with psuedoinverse, and indeed I need to solve a linear system with LU or some equivalent

Comment: @OriaGruber No you cannot do better. The pseudoinverse give the closest answer.

Comment: Yes I see. Ok, thank you very much.